# prepare a 45 minutes PhD interview presentation

Tags: phd, presentation, interview

I was asked to give a presentation in front of a group of people (they are leaders of different groups, because there might be collaboration with them). The presentation and QA will be one hour.

What topics I should give during this presentation?

My current plan is 1st-my brief introduction (major, experience). 2nd-my master thesis. 3rd-my research interest in this phd project.

Any suggestions are appreciated! It is a 45-min presentation, and I will spend one day with those group leaders. It will be like after one hour-QA, I might have a lunch with them, and I guess there might be some small talk.

Comment: Can you add context on what type of 'interview' this might be and who the audience is?

Comment: Can you explain the ":(" after the info that you will spend the day with your potential PhD supervisor? This is your chance to find out if you want to work with them for the next couple of years..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

The number-one rule for this type of presentation is to make it **clear and interesting** to your audience --- you want to show them that you will be the type of work colleague who can talk about interesting ideas and can explain those things in an understandable way.

In view of that objective, you should minimise talking about your major and experience (which are presumably already in your application documents and CV) and instead focus primarily on telling the audience about the interesting work you did in your Masters project and the interesting work you plan to do in PhD research.  Use your presentation to introduce interesting ideas that will hold the attention of your audience, explain this work in clear and simple terms that has respect to audience context, and through this exhibit your intellectual curiosity and your present state of knowledge.  Practice your presentation to ensure you are clear and not rushing it, and leave some time for a question period.

Comment: It is okay to say 'I am not an intelligent person' during a PhD interview? I think most of people are looking for smart people. I am not smart, but I work hard.

Comment: @mmmm As a joke/off-hand comment maybe ("I had to re-do this entire experiment because I am not an intelligent person"), but I genuinely struggle to imagine a situation where you would do it otherwise. The admissions committee (assuming it is one) is not a counseling service, and it generally would form their opinion on your personal traits based on how you present your work, not what you think of yourself ("not smart" and "work hard" are both incredibly subjective).

Comment: I've seen some students who self-diagnose as being of lower intelligence than their peers and say they make up for it with hard work.  I'm not averse to hearing that and it would be a perfectly reasonable sign of a commitment to honest self-reflection.  Ultimately, if a person meets the entry requirements for a PhD program, they must have had whatever mixture of relevant skills and abilities was required to acheive the things that qualified them (whether raw intelligence, dilligence, or some combination).